# Allow uploaded SharePoint files to be marked as "Checked-In"

Tags: sharepoint, vbscript

I just wrote a vbscript that uploads files into a shared folder. It works. The problem is that the default state of these files is "Check Out". So I have to manually select these files on the front-end to "Check In". This I believe defeats the purpose of my script. Is there a way around this? Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you.
Jake

P.S. Here is a sample code.

```
URL = "http://portal/projects/"
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objADOStream
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .LoadFromFile ("C:\VBScripts\SP\2014_Test_IC.txt")
    End With
content = objADOStream.Read
objXMLHTTP.open "PUT",URL & "2014_Test_IC.txt",False,"Username","Password"
objXMLHTTP.send content
WScript.Echo objXMLHTTP.status & ":" & objXMLHTTP.statusText
objADOStream.Close
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  You will get a much better response if you post some code that you've already attempted.

Comment: @PaulStock Hello Paul, I updated my initial post with a sample code. To further elaborate, the default state of newly uploaded documents is "Check Out" which can only be opened by other users as Read Only. What I wanted to do is incorporate in my script a routine that will set the documents as editable(can be checked out by other users).  To this end, as embarrassing as this may be, I have no idea.  Any help you or other folks can render will be much appreciated.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the Front Page Server Extensions.

Here is the official documentation for the check in document method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd585532%28v=office.11%29.aspx

Here's the code for uploading and then checking in a document.  It's very similar to yours and you can see at the end where you would fill in your values when calling the upload function.

```
  Function StringToByteArray(str)
   Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
   stream.Open
   stream.Type = 2 ''adTypeText
   stream.Charset = "ascii"
   stream.WriteText str
   stream.Position = 0
   stream.Type = 1 ''adTypeBinary
   StringToByteArray = stream.Read()
   stream.Close
End Function

Sub UploadFile(sourcePath, siteUrl, docName, title, checkincomment, userName, password)

   strHeader = "method=put+document%3a12.0.4518.1016" + _
      "&service_name=%2f" + _
      "&document=[document_name=" + Escape(docName) + _
      ";meta_info=[vti_title%3bSW%7c" + Escape(title) + "]]" + _
      "&put_option=overwrite,createdir,migrationsemantics" + _
      "&comment=" + _
      "&keep%5fchecked%5fout=false" + vbLf
   bytearray = StringToByteArray(strHeader)

   Set stream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
   stream.Open
   stream.Type = 1 ''adTypeBinary
   stream.Write byteArray

   Set stream2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
   stream2.Open
   stream2.Type = 1 ''adTypeBinary
   stream2.LoadFromFile sourcePath
   stream2.CopyTo stream, -1
   stream.Position = 0

   Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
   xmlHttp.open "POST", siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll", false, userName, password
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Vermeer-Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "FrontPage"
   xmlHttp.send stream

   If xmlHttp.status = 200 Then

       If Instr(xmlHttp.responseText, "successfully") = 0 Then

          MsgBox "ERROR: " & vbCrLf & xmlHttp.responseText       

       Else

          ''Checkin

          strHeader = "method=checkin+document%3a12.0.4518.1016" + _
             "&service_name=%2f" + _
             "&document_name=" & Escape(docName) + _
             "&comment=" + Escape(checkincomment) + _
             "&keep%5fchecked%5fout=false" + vbLf

          Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
          xmlHttp.open "POST", siteUrl + "/_vti_bin/_vti_aut/author.dll", false, userName, password
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "X-Vermeer-Content-Type","application/x-vermeer-urlencoded"
          xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "FrontPage"
          xmlHttp.send strHeader



       End If

   End If

   If xmlHttp.status / 100 <> 2 Then
      MsgBox "ERROR: status = " & xmlHttp.status & vbCrLf & xmlHttp.responseText
   End If

End Sub

UploadFile "C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Test File.zip", _
    "http://computername/Sites/sitename", _
    "Requirements/Test File.zip", _
    "Test title", _
    "Test checkin comment", _
    "MYDOMAIN\myusername", "mypassword"
MsgBox "Done"
```

I need to give credit to fmunkert for working this out:  [VBScript to Upload file to SharePoint DocLib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3787870/vbscript-to-upload-file-to-sharepoint-doclib)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure which sharepoint server version your running .... or that by applying the [KnowledgeVersion.CheckIn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd588181%28v=office.11%29.aspx) method in this specific example will be successful, but here is a test source code to try out regardless.

> The Checkin method checks in the current document. A check-in releases
>   the editing reservation placed on the document when it was checked out
>   and updates the content of the document.

```
Dim URL, objXMLHTTP, objADOStream
Dim content, Version

URL = "http://portal/projects/"
Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0")
Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    With objADOStream
        .Open
        .Type = 1
        .LoadFromFile ("C:\VBScripts\SP\2014_Test_IC.txt")
    End With
Set Version = CreateObject("CDO.KnowledgeVersion")
Version.Checkin URL & "2014_Test_IC.txt"
content = objADOStream.Read
objXMLHTTP.open "PUT",URL & "2014_Test_IC.txt",False,"Username","Password"
objXMLHTTP.send content
WScript.Echo objXMLHTTP.status & ":" & objXMLHTTP.statusText
objADOStream.Close
```

Comment: Hi All, thank you so much for the ideas. Now I have something to work on. @Rich, for some reason, I could not instantiate "CDO.KnowledgeVersion".  The error I get is "ActiveX component can't create object: 'CDO.KnowledgeVersion'".

Comment: Yeah, its probably too old. @Cam 's option is more recent.